# Navigations count in flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-getx

I need to show a pop up after user change 3 page in app.

How can I count number of navigations in flutter ?

I used getx for change pages in app and had observer analytics of firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can track the changed page using a variable. There is no such thing as `global variable` in dart programing language. So this is a way around implementing a global variable in dart.

**Steps:**
Create a file called `global.dart` and declare a variable

eg: `int pageCount = 0;`

now import this file as `import 'package:..../global.dart';`

and increment the `pageCount` variable wherever there is a `Navogator.push` or page change is triggered.

**Imp Note: If you use this way then on every app restart the `pageCount` variable resets (initialised) to 0 and the pop will be shown again to the user after `pageCount=3`**

---

Now if this can be avoided if you use a `sharedPreferences` plugin. Store the `pageCount` as a shared preferences. The update of the variable should be done in the same way as explained above.

Then on every app start read this variable if the variable == 3 then you can skip the showing of the popup.

plugin link: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

This post explains very well how to implement shared preferences in your flutter app: https://medium.com/flutterdevs/using-sharedpreferences-in-flutter-251755f07127

---

This is the most tedious way:

Now if you are not comfortable in using shared preferences then, you can store the variable in a text file or a JSON file using  path_provider plugin with the dart:io library.

everything explained here on reading and writing files : https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files

if you choose to use JSON file to save the variable then you can do as follows:

- open a file called `config.json` or `any_name.json`
- use file.writeAsStringSync('{"pageCount":3}'), whatever the page change count is at that instance.
- Read this file on every app start, check if the page count is 3, then implement your logic and so on.

Comment: yeah, after many search, this is the only way I have.
but i used GetX so i create global controller and handle data on it with get_storage.
Thanks